# py2app ends with error related to libgfortran.3.dylib

Tags: python, py2app

py2app ends with following error:

```
/usr/bin/strip: the __LINKEDIT segment does not cover the end of the file 
(can't be processed) in: test.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgfortran.3.dylib
stripping saved 1222348 bytes (88617336 / 89839684)
```

this last line of console output:

```
../Frameworks/libgfortran.3.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

how can I fix this?

I am using
Snow Leopard (x86_64)
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb  4 2011, 20:12:20)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)] on darwin

Answer (score 0):

First decide what architectures and OS versions you plan to build for.

Then make sure `libgfortran` and your other dependencies are compiled for these architecture(s).  (You can use `lipo -info` or `file` to print the architectures contained in a Mach-O binary).

Finally, if the architectures are a subset of those for which the version of Python you're using is built, either compile/use a version of Python built for only these architecture(s), or hack distutils to remove `-arch` flags (and add `-isysroot` if needed) as in [this script](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/py2app/apptemplate/setup.py).

Comment: @nicholas-riley: ok, I am kind of lost here. I am using py26-py2app-devel(0.5.3) from MacPorts. It's built universal. I have gcc44 from macports as well, although it's not default gcc. gcc44 is also built +universal but somehow libgfortran.3.dylib is only i386. How can I understand which gcc used by py2app? Finally, I don't actually need 64bit, this is not an enduser software yet, I am only testing at the moment on my own machine. What would be easiest way to get out?

Comment: distutils (which is what you're using with py2app) tries to call the compiler with the compilation flags that *it* was compiled with.  So if you're using Python from MacPorts, it'll use that version of Python.  I think MacPorts by default is 64-bit only, so your best bet may be to install one of the 32-bit Pythons from python.org and use that instead; probably easier than trying to fix gfortran's build process.